# Nginx ingress controller not reuse connection as experted

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, keep-alive

I have a on-prem K8s cluster with nginx ingress controller.
We has config Microservice and nginx to support keep alive connection.
Here is config on nginx:

```
keep-alive: 100
keep-alive-requests: 1000
upstream-keepalive-connections: 100
upstream-keepalive-requests: 10000
upstream-keepalive-timeout: 3600
```

with Microservice - Spring Boot, we also enable persistence connection with 3600s keepAliveTimeout and no limit number of keep alive request per a connection.

When testing with 10 ccu by jmetter. I can see that has created 30 connection between Microservice and nginx.
When testing by calling 10 requests sequentially from my PC, It also create 10 new connections.

Expected: if we have 1 ccu we only need to open 1 connection. If we have 10 ccu we need to open 10 connections.

Is possible to config connection pooling with nginx ingress controller (or haproxy) ?

Thanks

Comment: how many pods do you have do you have? what is a CCU?

Comment: I have 2 instance of each Ingress controller or Microservice. CCU mean: concurrent thread